# How can I change the numbers of a numbered list in Power Point?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm trying to create a numbered list as the content of a slide in Power Point 2010. Now, my numbering needs to start with `2.1` and go through to `2.6`. It should continue with `2.7` on the next slide.

```
2.1 foo
2.2 bar
2.3 baz
2.4 cookies
2.5 more stuff
2.6 even more stuff
```

Now, I have no real clue how to do that. I can't seem to set a starting number when using the numbered list button or looking at the details of it. Even if I create a numbered list, add two items and then indent the next item, it starts with `1`, but will not display `2.1` although it is clearly a sub point of number 2.

I'm now going to just not use a list at all and number it myself. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Powerpoint 2010 does not support the style you are after, but the numbering for the levels can start wherever you want.
I created 2 text boxes, and continued the test in the second box
[image: Bullets and numbering dialog box]
By opening up the **Bullets and Numbering** dialog box, (on the down arrow next to the buttons) I was able to change the *start at* number for my bullet list